# Etiquetas en columnas

Tags: r

Podemos poner etiquetas a las columnas de un df con label, por ejemplo

```
df <-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c(1,2,3),col3=c(1,2,3))

library(Hmisc)

label(df$col1)<-"ID"
label(df$col2)<-"Ventas"
label(df$col3)<-"Compras"
```

¿Cómo puedo enumerarlas con un bucle en plan...

```
   label(df$col1)<-"1"
   label(df$col2)<-"2"
   label(df$col3)<-"3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más sencillo, es iterar por cada columna y agregarle el índice:

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  Hmisc::label(df[, i]) <- paste(i)
}
```

O en su defecto, usando R base para prescindir de `Hmisc`:

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  attr(df[, i], "label") <- paste(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa funcional sería

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c(1,2,3),col3=c(1,2,3))

etiquetas <- 1:3 #Acá pueden ir valores arbitrarios siempre que sean del mismo largo que ncol(df)

df_etiquetado <- map2_df(df, etiquetas, ~`attr<-`(.x, "label", .y))
```

Uso `map2_df()` para iterar sobre dos listas: la lista de columnas (df) y la lista de etiquetas. Al ser `_df` va a regresarnos un data.frame y no una simple lista.

La función que uso tiene que recibir al menos dos argumentos, uno para `.x` y otro para `.y`. En este caso uso `attr<-`, que es una versión de `attr` con asignación: en lugar de hacer un subset de los atributos les asigna directamente un valor. De esta forma no tengo que hacer uso explícito del operador binario `<-`, que sería más complicado dentro de una llamada a `map`.

En R hay varias funciones `función<-` que tienen este comportamiento. Además de `attr<-` está `names<-` , para nombrar los elementos de una lista o vector, `colnames<-`, `levels<-`, `is.na<-` y otras. Sirven mucho para programación funcional, nos evitan tener que declarar la función y usar `{}` para delimitarla y usar dentro `<-`.

Usando

```
x <- as.character(lsf.str("package:base"))
x[str_detect(x, "<-")]
```

Obtienes una lista de todas las funciones con ese patrón dentro del paquete base.